# How to parameterize SQL for INSERT?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, parameterized-query

I have tried the code below but my SQL table is empty and there was no error message. Below is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Delivery_Inspection.Properties.Settings.TransitiondayConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

        String query = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Busnumber, Remarks, Dt1check1) VALUES (@bn, @rm, @dt1)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bn", label1.Text.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rm", richTextBox1.Text.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", this.dataGridView1[1, 0].Value);

            sqlconn.Open();
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Check Error
            if (result < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
        }
}
```

Comment: result will never be less than zero, since ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected.  If it's greater than zero, the query worked.

Comment: @LarsTech Understood. That is why I wrote the code where if no rows are inserted produce error message. There was no error message but the sql table is also empty. I don't know why.

Comment: @mjwills Noted. Changes has been made. Thanks

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Comment: Still, result will never be less than zero, so that error message will never appear.   And again, if result is greater than zero, then the query worked.  It's easy to get confused with what database you are looking at.  Double-check.

Comment: @LarsTech Understood. So, I've changed it to be more than 0 and the message would be `Update Successful`. When I run, even the successful message did not popup. But why, is then something wrong with my `INSERT`?

Comment: Time to use the debugger.  Put a stop line on there and see what happens when you run it.

Comment: @LarsTech My result is 1 for `if (result > 0)` and I've changed to `MessageBox.Show("OK");`. The message box came out but my sql table is still empty. Why?

Comment: Sometimes you are just looking at the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `sqlconn.Open();` before you create `command` and execute it

and I suggest to put it in uses as well:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Delivery_Inspection.Properties.Settings.TransitiondayConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            var query = "INSERT into Table1(Busnumber,Remarks,Dt1check1)VALUES (@bn,@rm,@dt1)";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bn", label1.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rm", richTextBox1.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", this.dataGridView1[1, 0].Value);
                var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Check Error
                if (result < 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my SQL table is still empty after the changes recommended.

Comment: use schema in Table name as well. It is possible you may accidentally created two tables and by default it uses `db` schema. At least in MS SQL server.

Comment: I am unsure about using `schema` correctly. What I did was put this code: `sqlconn.GetSchema("Table1");`under `sqlconn.Open();`. When I do this, I got an error of : **The requested collection (Table1) is not defined**. I don't even know what that means.

Comment: update to this
var query = "INSERT into `MySchema`.Table1(Busnumber,Remarks,Dt1check1)VALUES (@bn,@rm,@dt1)";

Comment: I did as per above `INSERT into MySchema.Table1(Busnumber,Remarks,Dt1check1)VALUES (@bn,@rm,@dt1)` but I got error of **Invalid object name 'MySchema.Table1'**

Comment: `MySchema` is your table's schema.use whatever you have like: `db.Table1`

Comment: Noted. I have changed to `INSERT into [dbo].[Table1](Busnumber,Remarks,Dt1check1)VALUES (@bn,@rm,@dt1)` where my schema is `dbo` but my sql table is still empty